# when i submit email form it send back my own email Django python

Tags: django

```
class ProjectListAndFormView(SuccessMessageMixin, ListView, FormView):
model = Project # data from database
template_name = 'mainpage/main.html'
context_object_name = 'list_projects' # name of the var in html template
queryset = Project.objects.all().order_by("-pub_date")#  list of all projects
object_list = None

form_class = ContactForm
success_url = '/' # After submiting the form keep staying on the same url
success_message = 'Your Form has been successfully submitted!'

def form_valid(self, form):
    # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    con = get_connection('django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend')
    send_mail(
        cd['name'],
        cd['message'],
        cd.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
        ['22agrandon@gmail.com'],
        fail_silently=False
    )
    return super(ProjectListAndFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

views.py

im having trouble with a form page on my website. Whenever i enter a random email on the email form part on the website it sends a succesful mail but from my own emayil even if i put a random email. How do i fix this so when someone enters their email, it sucesfully sends me an email from their email?

Comment: class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField(label='sr-only', widget=forms.TextInput(
   attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'class': 'form-control', 'id':'c_name'}))

   email = forms.EmailField(label='sr-only', widget=forms.TextInput(
   attrs={'placeholder': 'E-mail', 'class': 'form-control', 'id':'c_email'}),
   required=False)

   message = forms.CharField(label='sr-only', widget=forms.TextInput(
   attrs={'placeholder': 'Message', 'class': 'form-control', 'id':'c_message'}))

Comment: You mixed up the arguments. Change `['22agrandon@gmail.com']` to `[cd.get('email', '22agrandon@gmail.com')]`.